# On Item Creation: Warning/Confirmation dialog for invalid Item Name

Tags: content-editor, pipelines, validation, speak

I want to create a Warning/Confirmation dialog when certain items do not pass our custom item name validation rules. The user can still override the warning dialog via OK/Cancel Buttons.

I've tried working in the `createItem` pipeline but I cannot generate a SheerResponse dialog, nor am able to wait on the postback. Additionally, this doesn't stop the item creation when you `AbortPipeline()`

Overwriting the `item:create` command seems overkill as I just want to extend the existing functionality rather than overwrite it.

Is there a recommended pipeline/hook-point to accomplish this?

Comment: Are your validations more complicated than limiting the characters that can be used in the item name? If not, check out the `ItemNameValidation` setting.

Comment: Yes, it's more complicated.  We currently use that setting but we need an option for users to override the system blocking them.

Comment: Have you considered using SPE to provide the Insert Options and behind-the-scenes logic for validation and creation?